# My program gives me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java

I am writing a program to translate a phrase into pig latin by creating an array filled with the individual words of a string that the user inputs, then going through every individual word and changing it to pig latin, and printing it to the console. I usually get the error above when on the `while()` loop of my method:

```
    package UpGAMING;

    public class Methods {

public void Translator(String s, String[] index, int location) {

    while (index[location].length() > 0) {

        location++;

        if(index.length > 0)s = s + index[location].substring(1) + index[location].substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + "ay";

        System.out.println(s);
    } 
}
}
```

If I change the condition to simply **while(true)** I get the error of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 2 on this line:

```
        if(index.length > 0)s = s + index[location].substring(1) + index[location].substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + "ay";
```

Here is my class containing the **main()** method:

```
    package UpGAMING;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Basic {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Methods method = new Methods();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int indexer = 1;
    String ss = "";

    System.out.println("Enter the word or phrase you want to translate to Pig Latin:");
    input = keyboard.next();

    String[] output = input.split("\\s+");

    method.Translator(input, output, indexer);

    System.out.println();

}
}
```

Please provide a code block of what my code *should* look like as I am not an experienced programmer.

Comment: You should check if in index there exits the index location. I think there is your problem.

Comment: Your array doesn't have 2 elements. Mystery solved. You probably want to print out what you're getting back from `keyboard.next();` and see what the issue is.

Comment: What is the exit condition for your loop? An empty string?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't have two elements? I am not very experienced with arrays...

Comment: agim, what do you mean by exit condition?

Comment: @zjuventus14 when should the while loop stop executing?

Comment: @agim The loop should stop executing when the part of the array(one of the individual strings) has no characters, since I believe it is an array with no limit on capacity

Comment: I am still confused...What should my code look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and maybe you will understand what's wrong with your code

```
public class Methods {
    public void Translator(String s, String[] index, int location) {
        System.out.println("Index Length: " + index.length);
        System.out.println("Location: " + location);
        if (location >= index.length)
            System.out.println("Uppss.. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException :((( ");
        while (index[location].length() > 0) { 
          location++; 
          if(index.length > 0) {
              s = s + index[location].substring(1) 
                    + index[location].substring(0,1).toLowerCase() 
                    + "ay";
          }
          System.out.println(s);
       } 
   }
}
```

Try this..

```
public void Translator(String s, String l, String[] index)
{
  for (String word : index) {
    String s1=s, l1=l;
    if (word.length()> 0) {
      s1 = l1 + word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + "ay";
      l1 = s1;
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
  }
}
```

Comment: So... How can I make it so that my location will not be >= the index.length? Thanks for your help

Comment: 1. you pass a 0 as location (now you pass 1, you want to check the first element) 

2. you should change your while loop to `while (location < index.length && index[location].length() > 0)` and 

3. You should increment location at the bottom of the loop

Comment: When I use this strategy...It works, but not with multiple words...how do I fix this?

Comment: When I use this strategy...It works, but not when I have multiple words in the string that was split into the array. Can you help me? Here's my current code for my Method class: `package UpGAMING;

public class Methods {
 public void Translator(String s, String l, String[] index, int location) {
  while (location < index.length && index[location].length() > 0) {
   if (index.length > 0) {
    s = l + index[location].substring(1)
      + index[location].substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + "ay";
    l = s;
    location++;
   }
  }
  System.out.println(s);
 }
}`

Comment: Check the second method. I changed the signature, since I think you don't need the location .. hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

In main, you read input with `Scanner.next()` and then split it on whitespace. But Scanner by default already splits on whitespace and `next()` only gives you the next word on input. So I would read the input with `next()` in a loop, until you encounter the agreed terminator (e.g., the word END). Alternatively, you could read with `nextLine()` instead of `next()` and then split as you do.

Then process the array in Translator. I would take a guard such as `location < index.length` and move `location++` to the end of the loop.